# travel writing recommendations - on or off topic?

Tags: discussion

I like how many travel guides, specifically the Rough Guide and Lonely Planet series, give recommendations for travel writing about specific countries. I wish I'd read more of those books before I'd done my travelling. I also think it would be great to have a big-list style, ever expanding reference list of travel writing on a country-by-country basis, seeing as how that would theoretically be more up-to-date and comprehensive than your standard travel guide. Would people consider this on-topic?

Comment: I assume you mean specific books about countries? Like how the LP recommends 'The Great Game' for Uzbekistan, Tajikistan etc?

Answer (score 4):

No, I would say this is not on-topic as it does not fit the standard Q&A format of StackExchange websites. It is a nice idea, but this is not the place for it. Perhaps a section for external links on Wikitravel pages would be helpful  but I'm assuming their community too would restrict the number of links for each entry.